# A puzzle of romance

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus

**What does the heart at the bottom depict (specifically)?**

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image at the bottom depicts...

> ...the iconic upside-down kissing scene from the movie [Spiderman (2002)](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/movies/movie-features/spider-man-tobey-maguire-suffocating-during-upside-down-kiss-1235138931/amp/)

---

The persons in the first image are

> 1) Sarah Kernochan who directed 'Strike!' (2008).
> Clue: Bowling alley.
> 2) Juan Diego Solanos who directed 'Upside Down' (2012).
> Clue: Upside down image of the director.
> 3) Walter Salles who directed 'On the Road' (2012).
> Clue: Road.
> 4) Richard Loncraine who directed 'Wimbledon' (2004).
> Clue: Wimbledon tennis courts.

> All these movies feature actress Kirsten Dunst. So number '1' must be Kirsten Dunst.

---

The persons in the second image are

> 1) Edward Zwick who directed 'Pawn Sacrifice' (2014).
> Clue: An image of pawn.
> 2) Jason Reitman who directed 'Labor Day' (2013).
> Clue: An image of laborers.
> 3) Steven Soderbergh who directed 'The Good German' (2006).
> Clue: An image of Oskar Schindler.
> 4) Ben Stiller who directed 'Tropic Thunder' (2008).
> Clue: An image of tropical forest.

> All these movies feature actor Tobey Maguire. So number '2' must be Tobey Maguire.

---

> So finally, picturing 1 as Kirsten Dunst and 2 as upside-down Tobey Maguire in the final image gives us that iconic upside-down kissing scene!

Comment: That's it! Everything looks good. Well done!

Comment: Thank you. Very creative puzzle. As soon as I deciphered 1 and 2, I had that 'aha' moment!